# Equivalence of old & new IPv4-Mapped IPv6 representation?

Tags: ipv6

The old definition of an IPv4 as an IPv6 address is (using 127.0.0.1):

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:7f00:0001
```

while the current definition has the 6th component as FFFF:

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:7f00:0001
```

Should these be considered equivalent or is there some subtle distinction in the way they should be treated? Currently I am looking in the context of where the value was persisted and impact on assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example is an IPv4-Compatible IPv6 address, and those are deprecated.

Your second example is an IPv4-Mapped IPv6 address. You are allowed, and encouraged, to use a mixed notation (e.g. `::ffff:127.0.0.1`), or the IPv6 notation (e.g. `::ffff:7f00:0001`).

[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-5), is a standard which discusses IPv6 representation. It notes:

> **5.  Text Representation of Special Addresses**
>
> Addresses such as IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses, ISATAP [[RFC5214](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5214)], and
> IPv4-translatable addresses [[ADDR-FORMAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#ref-ADDR-FORMAT)] have IPv4 addresses
> embedded in the low-order 32 bits of the address.  These addresses
> have a special representation that may mix hexadecimal and dot
> decimal notations.  The decimal notation may be used only for the
> last 32 bits of the address.  For these addresses, mixed notation is
> RECOMMENDED if the following condition is met: the address can be
> distinguished as having IPv4 addresses embedded in the lower 32 bits
> solely from the address field through the use of a well-known prefix.
> Such prefixes are defined in [[RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)] and [[RFC2765](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2765)] at the time of
> this writing.  If it is known by some external method that a given
> prefix is used to embed IPv4, it MAY be represented as mixed
> notation.  Tools that provide options to specify prefixes that are
> (or are not) to be represented as mixed notation may be useful.
>
> There is a trade-off here where a recommendation to achieve an
> exact match in a search (no dot decimals whatsoever) and a
> recommendation to help the readability of an address (dot decimal
> whenever possible) does not result in the same solution.  The above
> recommendation is aimed at fixing the representation as much as
> possible while leaving the opportunity for future well-known
> prefixes to be represented in a human-friendly manner as tools
> adjust to newly assigned prefixes.
>
> The text representation method noted in [Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4) should be applied
> for the leading hexadecimal part (i.e., ::ffff:192.0.2.1 instead of
> 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:192.0.2.1).

Comment: If I do encounter an IPv4-Compatible IPv6 address in my database (or any data source), is it safe to simply convert it to an IPv4-Mapped IPv6 address?

Comment: It should be mandatory since IPv4-Compatible addresses are deprecated, but it depends on what is using the address, and how it is being used. If it is really an IPv4 address in a database which uses IPv6 notation in order to store both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, then you probably don't want to do that. If it is really an IPv6 address, then you probably do want to change it.

Comment: So, if I understand: a field that is storing both IPV4 and IPv6 address in a database, then I would use the 'IPv4-Compatible' address for a connection that was IPv4 and 'IPv4-Mapped IPv6' address for a connection that was made via IPv6?

Comment: That can get messy. IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses are really a kludge without much use, and you don't often find them unless someone really doesn't know what they are doing. I don't advocate mixing IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in a database, either, since they are two separate protocols. It's really going to boil down to what is being used for what.

Comment: just for info, this "recommended" way lead to [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-sip-ipv6-abnf-fix#section-3.1) ABNF what a world